# Adaptive piecewise linear regression of empirical distribution function

Tags: regression, sampling, monte-carlo, convergence

I need to find the best, in the mean-squared sense, piecewise linear regression of an emprical density function (eCDF, which I do not know but can be sampled online) on the largest possible uniformally distributed grid. The domain is all reals and the residuals are normally distributed.

I am envisioning a Monte-Carlo-like algorithm that samples and *h*-refines until the convergence criterion is satisfied.

Does anyone know of such an algorithm?

Comment: You will get the lowest possible MSE by having breakpoints at all $x$ values present in your data. So are you looking for piecewise linear regression with fixed breakpoints, or with a fixed *number* of breakpoints?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thank you for your response. Technically with a fixed number of breakpoints, but no more than is necessary to satisfy the criterion (i.e as opposed to a direct minimization)

Comment: Hm. Increasing the number of breakpoints will always improve the in-sample fit, so I'm not sure which criterion you are thinking about. You could use something like in the [`segmented`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/index.html) package for R with an increasing number of breakpoints, and stop when your in-sample MSE dips below some threshold. Or determine the number of breakpoints using its`selgmented()` function (no typo). Does that answer your question?